# из pytest никак не обратится к logging

Tags: python, логирование, pytest

Как из pytest обратится к logging и записывать логи в файл ?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, зачем вам это? И что мешает вам обратиться?

Comment: Импортировать модуль, логировать что надо, выводить в файл. Или о чем вопрос?

Comment: Из тестов pytest logging не запускается, файл создает, но ничего не записывает. Если использовать мою функцию для логирования из обычного скрипта(не теста) то все работает, а из теста нет

Comment: Есть Live Logging в самом `pytest`e, к примеру `pytest -o log_cli=1 --log-file=my-log.txt`, правда, недостаток в том, что логи будут выдаваться и в терминале тоже. В [моем ответе на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51633600/2650249) есть больше примеров настройки. Если нужна более ручная настройка, есть [`pytest-logger`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-logger/), но я никогда им не пользовался, ничего сказать не могу.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pytest
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import logging
import allure


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\webdrivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')


# Logger

logging.basicConfig(filename="C:/Folder/test.log",
                    format='%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')


logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

У меня работает такое начало, кастомно в тест добавляю что то такое:

```
logging.error('Error - url1_input module', exc_info=True)
```